# Nested Array in Redux Resetting Value in React

Tags: reactjs, redux, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I have an array called `products` and inside of that I have a field called `productCategory`. My problem is that its clearing up other values of the array.

Codesandboxis here
[CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/complete-autocomplete-productimages-snt6o?file=/src/components/ProductInputs/index.js)

```
case appConstants.CHANGE_PRODUCT_CATEGORY:
  return {
    ...state,
    products: state.products.map((product) => {
      product?.productCode === action.payload?.productCode
        ? {
            ...product,
            productCategory: action.payload.productCategory
          }
        : product;
    })
  };
```

Comment: FYI, this will be much simpler if you use [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux) to write your Redux logic, as it uses Immer to let you write "mutating" immutable state update logic without having to use a bunch of nested spread operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's because you have missed `return` keyword inside map function.

```
case appConstants.CHANGE_PRODUCT_CATEGORY:
    return {
    ...state,
    products: state.products.map((product) => {
      return product?.productCode === action.payload?.productCode
        ? {
            ...product,
            productCategory: action.payload.productCategory
          }
        : product;
    })
};
```

Comment: If my answer is correct, I would appreciate it if you mark it as accpeted response.

Comment: Also, when I type something in productName, it resets its value after selecting from ProductCategory?

Comment: Right, I didn't check your sandbox, I just guess the problem by your code, let's check your sandbox

Comment: Could you please take look at this [SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/old-autocomplete-productimages-hugo-forked-rrqo0?file=/src/components/ProductInputs/index.js) to check it works crrectly or not?

Comment: Can you point what did you change? It seems that's my codesanbox link. It should a new link

Comment: It's a forked version from you sandbox and I've just changed `enableReinitialize: false` in formik config. does it work as you expected?

Comment: If I did that. If I select from the dropdown, i can't see other options of it unless I clear it out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239869/discussion-between-saeed-shamloo-and-joseph).